# C# EF6 Update Values to non related tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, entity-framework-6

I have a question about updating a non related table.

I have a TableA which has:

```
Id     Code      Value(Int)
1      2201      3
2      2202      5
```

And a TableB which has:

```
Id     Code      Value(Int)
1      2201      2
2      2202      1
```

I need to Update a table (TableC) which is non related with both TableA and TableB with Sum of Values from TableA and TableB.

TableB:

```
Code       SumValues
2201       5
2202       6
```

Everytime I add values to TableA and TableB, I need to Update TableC with:
Sum (Existing Values in TableC + Current Value added to TableA + Current Value added to TableB)

Is this possible?
What kind of relation between tables do I need?
How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. You have to give some direction, ideally by showing something you already tried.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to achieve this, so I didn't try anything yet... I have no idea, no directions, nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Your tableC should be like this :

```
Id     Code     SumValues

1       2201       5
2       2202       6
```

You have to manually insert the values into TableC when you update the TableA and TableB.The only relationship on it is `FK` relationship with the `Code` field.Hope you have another table for maintaining `Codes`.Like a Master table for `Codes`.

Comment: Yes, I have a Table that holds `Code`. What do you mean by "You have to manually insert..."? Do you mean literally by hand? There's no way to insert values as we update TableA and TableB?

Comment: yes,I meant that way.If you need to do it auto,then you have to write a `trigger` on the db side.